# Raspberry Pi 3 Web Polling

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import urllib.request
import urllib.response
import urllib.error
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT)
true = 1
while(true):
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('xxxxxxxxxx')
        status = response.read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print (e.code)

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print (e.args)

    print (status)  
    if  status=='ON':
        print ("setting GPIO 40 ")
        GPIO.output(40,True)
    elif status=='OFF':
        GPIO.output(40,False)
```

Error im getting is status is not defined. If i define status as a empty string, the output is not displaying. I am trying to control my Rpi GPIO using a website. I used this link as guidance https://medium.com/@softxide/remote-control-raspberrypi-leds-from-web-browser-ui-84205993b98f.
Thank u in advanced.

Comment: The `request.read()` will return the byte encoded html page. not the simple status that you are expecting. It will certainly not the POST request sent from the html page (http://softxide.com/iot/home_auto/).

Comment: You may want to consider using http.server which allows you to implement GET and POST requests for such application without a need of web server. See https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It helps a lot. :)